# Превратить pandas dataframe колонку со строками вида 1,2,3 в список цифр

Tags: python, pandas

Есть Пандас вида:

```
      Seen          Buyed
0   0,1,2,3,4,5     NaN
1   0, 2            NaN   
........
```

Колонка - `Seen` строки, которые на самом деле список цифр. Надо эту колонку превратить в один общий список всех цифр:

```
[0,1,2,3,4,5,0,2...]
```

А потом сделать частотный словарь)))

Comment: На русском stackoverflow принято задавать вопросы на русском языке. Переведите пожалуйста.

Comment: Извините. Есть Пандас вида выше. Колонка - Seen строки, которые на самомо деле список цифр. Надо эту колонку превратить в один общий список всех цифр. А потом сделать частотный словарь)))

Comment: У вопроса есть кнопка `править`, нажмите ее, и переведите там вопрос, потому что его скорее всего закрою за несоответствие правилам сайта.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Склеить строки в столбце Pandas DataFrame можно используя метод [Series.str.cat()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.cat.html):

```
In [294]: s = df['Seen'].str.cat(sep=',')

In [295]: s
Out[295]: '0,1,2,3,4,5,0, 2'
```

можно разбить CSV строки в списки:

```
In [304]: df['Seen'].str.split(',\s*')
Out[304]:
0    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
1                [0, 2]
Name: Seen, dtype: object

In [305]: df['Seen'].str.split(',\s*').sum()
Out[305]: ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '0', '2']
```

Частотный словарь:

```
In [311]: df['Seen'].str.split(',\s*').apply(pd.Series).stack().astype(int).value_counts()
Out[311]:
2    2
0    2
5    1
4    1
3    1
1    1
dtype: int64
```

без преобразования в числа (int):

```
In [312]: df['Seen'].str.split(',\s*').apply(pd.Series).stack().value_counts()
Out[312]:
2    2
0    2
3    1
4    1
1    1
5    1
dtype: int64

In [313]: df['Seen'].str.split(',\s*').apply(pd.Series).stack().value_counts().to_dict()
Out[313]: {'0': 2, '1': 1, '2': 2, '3': 1, '4': 1, '5': 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы сразу частотный словарь сделать:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> df['Seen'].str.split(',').map(lambda lst: Counter(map(int, lst))).sum()
Counter({0: 2, 2: 2, 1: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1})
```

Если промежуточный список нужен:

```
>>> [n for lst in df['Seen'].str.split(',') for n in map(int, lst)]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 2]
```